# How to check the components that contribute to the size of the SQL data and log files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am looking at sql server database data and log file.

I want to check the components that contribute to the size of the SQL data and log files. For example - of the file size, how much is the actual data/log content, how much is available to be reclaimed.

What command can be used to get this information?

Comment: Please check this article. In SSMS you have reporta available to show disk usage by DB and log.  https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/01/sql-server-ssms-disk-usage-report/

Answer (score 2):

There is a DMV that breaks down this information by file per database:

`SELECT * FROM sys.master_files WHERE database_id = DB_ID('YourDB')`

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)